# Minimal perimeter of a triangle

Tags: proof-verification, triangles

> Imagine a triangle with a base $[0, s]$ and a height $h$. ($s, h \gt 0$)
>
> For what orthocentre $x$ does the triangle have a minimal perimeter and how long is it?

Now, the proof starts with:

Assume $(x, h)$ is the third edge point of the triangle (next to $(0, 0$) and ($s, 0$)), then the perimeter is identical with

$$s + \sqrt{x^2 + h^2} + \sqrt{(x - s)^2 + h^2}.$$

How did he conclude that?

Comment: This is true if the triangle is right angled, such that the orthocentre is also a vertex.

Comment: He concluded by dropping the perpendicular from $(x, h)$ to $(x, 0)$ and using the Pythagorean theorem on the two right triangles that just appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image: Click here to see a picture]

The two diagonal sides of the triangle are given by Pythagoras' Theorem

Edit:

What if I add the orthocentre in like this? I assume $x$ is the $x$ coordinate of the orthocentre $C$?

[image: Click here to see another picture]

Comment: Is there any reason the picture is a link and not an embed? Is it too big?

Comment: No, I don't think so. The orthocenter is the point where $h$ meets the base $[0,s]$

Comment: Your second example is way more enlightening, thank you! :-) Your interpretation of $x$ as a coordinate on the $x$-axis does also seem correct - although I can't tell you for sure, our professor just threw that one in. (he has this kind of attitude)

Answer (score 2):

$f(z)=\sqrt{h^2+z^2}$ is a convex function on $[0,s]$, hence
$$ f(x)+f(s-x) \geq 2\, f\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)$$
and equality is achieved only at $x=\frac{s}{2}$.
 With a more geometric approach, let we consider the following configuration: $\ell$ is a line parallel to $AB$ at a distance $h$ from $AB$ and $B'$ is the symmetric of $B$ with respect to $\ell$. For any $C\in\ell$,
$$ AC+CB = AC+CB' \geq AB' $$
by the triangle inequality, and equality holds only if the projection of $C$ on $AB$ is the midpoint of $AB$.

[image]